# Extract Photos from android device

Tags: android

I'm using that class to extract photos and put them in a textview

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
TextView view = new TextView(this);
Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, null, null, null,null);
String image= "";
while (cur.moveToNext()) {
  image+= "From :" + cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE));      
}
view.setText(image);
setContentView(view);
}
}
```

But i'm getting that list of errors

```
03-10 17:14:47.124: E/AndroidRuntime(8872): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-10 17:14:47.124: E/AndroidRuntime(8872): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start                activity ComponentInfo{com.example.sms/com.example.sms.MainActivity}:     java.lang.NullPointerException
03-10 17:14:47.124: E/AndroidRuntime(8872):     at     android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2313)
03-10 17:14:47.124: E/AndroidRuntime(8872):     at     android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2365)
03-10 17:14:47.124: E/AndroidRuntime(8872):     at     android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:156)
03-10 17:14:47.124: E/AndroidRuntime(8872):     at     android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
03-10 17:14:47.124: E/AndroidRuntime(8872):     at     android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-10 17:14:47.124: E/AndroidRuntime(8872):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
03-10 17:14:47.124: E/AndroidRuntime(8872):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5336)
03-10 17:14:47.124: E/AndroidRuntime(8872):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-10 17:14:47.124: E/AndroidRuntime(8872):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-10 17:14:47.124: E/AndroidRuntime(8872):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
03-10 17:14:47.124: E/AndroidRuntime(8872):     at     com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
03-10 17:14:47.124: E/AndroidRuntime(8872):     at     dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-10 17:14:47.124: E/AndroidRuntime(8872): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-10 17:14:47.124: E/AndroidRuntime(8872):     at         com.example.sms.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:21)
    03-10 17:14:47.124: E/AndroidRuntime(8872):     at     android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5122)
03-10 17:14:47.124: E/AndroidRuntime(8872):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1081)
03-10 17:14:47.124: E/AndroidRuntime(8872):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2277)
03-10 17:14:47.124: E/AndroidRuntime(8872):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: Where is 33 line in MainActivity? You have null there

Comment: I edited my post so check it please now

Comment: Likely your variable cur is null. Does your phone really have external storage (SD card)?

Comment: No my phone has not SD card . I want to extract images from gallerie and save them into "image" so it will be shown in a textview . that's all !!

Comment: Try to change EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI to INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI

Comment: I changed it but i still have the same problem !!!!